# Remove points in square matrix in order to get a circle

Tags: geometry

Okay, so let's say i have a square. It's 5 long, 5 wide. And in this square is around 20 000 points all in one plane. How would I go about removing the points that would make a circle, a square? [I would need to remove all points located in the red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsdTV.png)

Keep in mind [coordinates of these points are real, decimal numbers. How would i check if a point is located in the red section? What bounds should it pass to be in the red area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say that the square and the circle are centered around the origin in a coordinate plane. It then follows that since the side length of the square is $5$, the radius of the circle is $\frac{5}{2}$.

We can say the circle's equation is:

$$x^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = \frac{9}{4}$$

We cannot express the square in terms of an equation, but rather an area bounded by multiple lines:

The region bounded by:

$$x = 5 \\ x = -5 \\y=5 \\ y = -5$$

Therefore, when trying choosing a point $(x, y)$ in the coordinate plane, if we want this point to be inside the square but outside the circle, then we would want a point $(x, y)$ such that:

$$x^2 + y^2 > \frac{9}{4} \\ -5 \le x \le 5 \\ -5 \le y \le 5$$

Hope that helped. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score -2):

If you want a circle of center $O(x_O, y_O)$ and radius $r$, then you need to remove all points $M(x,y)$ such that :$$(x-x_O)^2 + (y-y_O)^2 > r^2$$

Comment: you still need to make sure the point in the square, as stated by the OP

Comment: Sorry, I understood it as the square was the whole working area!